# Doctrine get entities distributed over hours

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

My problem: I need to get count(orders) from several shops distributed over hours. Ofcourse `Order` contain `createdAt` field, and bedirectional `ManyToOne` relation to `Shop`.

Can it be done through DQL or I should use plain SQL, or i should get orders and sort them in a loop?

What is the best practices? Expected result in Excel is as below.

[image]

My current solution:

Repository:

```
public function findSortedToday()
{
    $orders = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('HOUR(o.createdAt) AS oCreated')
        ->addSelect('SUM( od.dishPrice ) AS odSum')
        ->addSelect('(os.name) AS oShop')
        ->innerJoin('o.shop', 'os')
        ->innerJoin('o.dishes', 'od')
        ->groupBy('oCreated')
        ->addGroupBy('os')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $orders;
}
```

Controller:

```
    ...
    $ordersByHourArray = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("TerminalBundle:Order")->findSortedToday();        
    foreach ($ordersByHourArray as $data)
    {
        $resByHourArray[$data["oShop"]][$data["oCreated"]] = $data["odSum"]*1;
    }
    foreach ($resByHourArray as $shop => $data)
    {
        for ($h = 0; $h <= 23; $h++){
            if (!array_key_exists($h, $data)) $resByHourArray[$shop][$h] = 0;
        }
        ksort($resByHourArray[$shop]);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want number of orders split horizontally, i.e., row-wise.

```
select s.id shop_id,
       concat(case when date_format(now(),'%H') > 12 
       then concat(date_format(now(),'%H') - 12,' PM') 
       else concat(date_format(now(),'%H'),' AM') end
       ,' - ',case when date_format(now(),'%H') + 1 > 12 
       then concat(date_format(now(),'%H') + 1 - 12,' PM') 
       else concat(date_format(now(),'%H') + 1,' AM') end) window,
       count(*) orders
from orders o
left join shops s
on s.id = o.shop_id
group by s.id, window;
```

If you want the number of orders split vertically, i.e., column-wise.

```
select s.shop_id,
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 0 then o.order_id else 0 end) 'midnight - 1 AM',
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 1 then o.order_id else 0 end) '1 - 2 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 2 then o.order_id else 0 end) '2 - 3 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 3 then o.order_id else 0 end) '3 - 4 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 4 then o.order_id else 0 end) '4 - 5 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 5 then o.order_id else 0 end) '5 - 6 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 6 then o.order_id else 0 end) '6 - 7 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 7 then o.order_id else 0 end) '7 - 8 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 8 then o.order_id else 0 end) '8 - 9 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 9 then o.order_id else 0 end) '9 - 10 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 10 then o.order_id else 0 end) '10 - 11 AM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 11 then o.order_id else 0 end) '11 - noon',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 12 then o.order_id else 0 end) 'noon - 1 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 13 then o.order_id else 0 end) '1 - 2 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 14 then o.order_id else 0 end) '2 - 3 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 15 then o.order_id else 0 end) '3 - 4 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 16 then o.order_id else 0 end) '4 - 5 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 17 then o.order_id else 0 end) '5 - 6 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 18 then o.order_id else 0 end) '6 - 7 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 19 then o.order_id else 0 end) '7 - 8 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 20 then o.order_id else 0 end) '8 - 9 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 21 then o.order_id else 0 end) '9 - 10 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 22 then o.order_id else 0 end) '10 - 11 PM',       
       count(distinct case when hour(now()) = 23 then o.order_id else 0 end) '11 PM - midnight'      
from shops s inner join orders o on o.shop_id = s.shop_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *key* to group by in the `SELECT` clause to match your needs (simplified example):

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(MONTH(date), '-', DAY(date), '-', HOUR(date)) AS daytime,
  shop,
  COUNT(id) as cnt 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY daytime, shop;
```

> To play around: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67285/2

---

Currently you want to select aggregations of a single day only, then the `HOUR` function is sufficient for the group key. Adopted to your code, that should look as follows:

```
public function findSortedToday()
{
    $orders = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('HOUR(o.createdAt) AS oCreated')
        ->addSelect('SUM( od.dishPrice ) AS odSum')
        ->addSelect('os.name AS oShop')
        ->innerJoin('o.shop', 'os')
        ->innerJoin('o.dishes', 'od')
        ->groupBy('oCreated')
        // group by column name, not relation name
        ->addGroupBy('oShop')
        // limit to single day
        ->where('o.createdAt = :day')
        ->setParameter('day', $day)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    return $orders;
}
```

Of course, you can select from multiple days, but then you'll need to adjust the `GROUP BY` key accordingly.